# Displaying multiple models on one template

Tags: django

I have a template which displays a master detail form represented by a formset object. That part is working fine. I have a second detail model which is read-only that I would like to display on the same template as the master-detail form.

My view:

```
def order_edit(request, pk):
  order = get_object_or_404(Orders, pk=pk)

  if request.method == "POST":
    form = OrderForm(request.POST, instance=order)

    if form.is_valid():
        order = form.save(commit=False)
        lineitem_formset = LineFormSet(request.POST, instance=order)

        if lineitem_formset.is_valid():
            order.save()
            lineitem_formset.save()
        #order.date_ordered = timezone.now()
        #order.save()
        return redirect('order_list')
else:
    form = OrderForm(instance=order)
    #lineitem_formset = LineFormSet(instance=Orders()) This was wrong. It was calling a new instance of Orders which was blank
    lineitem_formset = LineFormSet(instance=order)
    modification_formset = ModificationFormSet(instance=order)
return render(request, "orders/order_edit.html", {"form": form, "lineitem_formset": lineitem_formset,"modification_formset": modification_formset })
```

I have read a number of posts on this topic but cannot seem to make sense of rendering the third model on my template. Here are my models.

```
class LineitemInfo(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey('Orders')
    line_item_num = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    item_description = models.CharField(max_length=1020, blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    unit_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    line_account_code = models.CharField(max_length=260, blank=True, null=True)
    options = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    option_num = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('order', 'line_item_num'),)

class Orders(models.Model):
    pr_num = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    po_num = models.CharField(max_length=56, blank=True, null=True)
    task_order_num = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    credit_card_id = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    vendor_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    order_description = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True, null=True)
    predicted_order_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    requestor = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)

class Modifications(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey('Orders', editable=False)
    mod_num = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
    mod_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
    mod_amount = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
    mod_description = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
    mod_performenddate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
    optionyear = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('order', 'mod_num'),)
```

It is the third model that I am trying to render on the template. The first two are rendered as part of a formset. TIA.

Comment: what are you asking?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. If you want to display instances of Modification, you just need to pass them to the template.

Comment: I think that I have gotten myself 'wound around the axle' and am probably missing a simple solution. Do I pass Modification separately or do I pass it as part of the 'order_new' view?